# Azure DevOps yaml pipeline : how to know which branch is being checked out?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I currently have my YAML pipeline and my application's source code in two different branches.

I was trying find evidence that what is being checked out is indeed the source code's branch and not my pipeline's branch.

I see that the checkout call at the end of the `git fetch` is to a **specific commit**, not to the **specified branch name**.

This is my resources definition:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoName
    type: git
    name: 'MyRepository'  # repository in Azure DevOps
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - UAT
```

and in one of my steps I do a `checkout: RepoName`.

I was expecting a `git checkout UAT` after pulling the source code, but as said I see a checkout of a specific commit.

How can I be sure about which branch is being checked out?

Comment: Keep in mind that a specific commit hash is a much better ID as to what code is being deployed, rather than a branch name. You can even have multiple branches' heads being at the same commit ID, so a branch name alone doesn't tell you what's going on. The specific commit hash is exact.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the build pipeline will check out the single commit that triggered the current pipeline run. When you manual, or via other methods, trigger a pipeline run, the run will check out the latest commit on default branch or the branch you specify.

However, no matter what methods triggers the pipeline run, you can use the predefined build variable **`Build.SourceBranch`** or **`Build.SourceBranchName`** to get the branch name where the commit is checked out from.

To view more details, you can see "[**Use predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)".

Typical syntax to display is:

```
steps:
- bash: echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
```

In addition, you also can go to the root of the local repository, and execute the [**git branch**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command. This command will output the name of the current branch.
For example:

```sh
git branch --show-current
```

If current branch is master, the output:

```sh
master
```

*Note that a number of people have reported that this produces no output*

Comment: git branch --show-current doesn't work for me. It looks like the git branch doesn't produce any output.

Comment: I also have this issue with `git branch --show-current` showing no output. I am only doing this to troubleshoot someother infuriatingly opaque issue. Very frustrating.

Comment: I think azure devops will checkout the repo in a detached head state, you can not use `git branch` to show the current branch. You have to use the variable `Build.SourceBranch`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ref`

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: string  # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
    type: enum  # see the following "Type" topic
    name: string  # repository name (format depends on `type`)
    ref: string  # ref name to use; defaults to 'refs/heads/master'
    endpoint: string  # name of the service connection to use (for types that aren't Azure Repos)
    trigger:  # CI trigger for this repository, no CI trigger if skipped (only works for Azure Repos)
      branches:
        include: [ string ] # branch names which will trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # branch names which will not
      tags:
        include: [ string ] # tag names which will trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # tag names which will not
      paths:
        include: [ string ] # file paths which must match to trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # file paths which will not trigger a build
```

so it would be

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoName
    type: git
    name: 'MyRepository'  # repository in Azure DevOps
    ref: 'UAT'
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - UAT
```

Comment: Could I ask you to comment a bit further on your suggestion? What does adding ref achieve and what happens if not there? Thanks

Comment: Done as suggested yet I still see something like `git checkout --progress --force ff8a52b0b7da6599d233d2d6565f085e9344d81f` and even increasing the log verbosity there is no evidence of what branch is being checked out

Answer (score 0):

In `ref` property you can set like this: `ref: 'refs/heads/UAT'`

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoName
    type: git
    name: 'MyRepository'  # repository in Azure DevOps
    ref: 'refs/heads/UAT'
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - UAT
```

Then in `steps`, you need to add `- checkout: RepoName`

Here is my sample you can refer to:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

trigger: none

resources:
      repositories:
      - repository: RepoName
        type: git
        name: '{proName}/{repoName}'  # repository in Azure DevOps
        ref: 'refs/heads/dev'    

steps:
  - checkout: RepoName
```

In build summary page:

[image]

In log :

[image]

Comment: Does it make any difference writing `refs/head/dev` instead of simply `dev`?

Comment: Here I just follow the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories) in the document, the actual test results show no difference.